# Passing parameters in a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am passing where clause parameter values from a program however when I am sending at least one one value I get the result however if I am sending all parameters as null no output is coming, i want a query such that if all parameters are sent as null will display all the records in the database

following is the query which retrieves values if one condition is satisfied

```
SELECT * 
  FROM STUDENT
  LEFT JOIN COURSE
    ON STUDENT.COURSE_ID = COURSE.COURSE_ID
 WHERE STUDENT.STD_ID = null
   OR STUDENT.STD_NAME = null
   OR STUDENT.STD_START_DATE = null
   OR STUDENT.STD_END_DATE = null
   OR STUDENT.STD_GENDER = null
   OR STUDENT.COURSE_ID = null;
```

Comment: `STD_START_DATE =null` does not work you need to use `STD_START_DATE IS null`

Comment: How are you passing the variables across from your program? I don't see any paramters in your example sql statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try below,

```
SELECT *
FROM   STUDENT
       LEFT JOIN COURSE
              ON STUDENT.COURSE_ID = COURSE.COURSE_ID
WHERE  STUDENT.STD_ID IS NULL
        OR STUDENT.STD_NAME IS NULL
        OR STUDENT.STD_START_DATE IS NULL
        OR STUDENT.STD_END_DATE IS NULL
        OR STUDENT.STD_GENDER IS NULL
        OR STUDENT.COURSE_ID IS NULL
```

Comment: actually my question is that i require a query such that if all values go as null as assigned in the above query i want another query to execute which fetches all the data without any condition like SELECT *
FROM   STUDENT
       LEFT JOIN COURSE
              ON STUDENT.COURSE_ID = COURSE.COURSE_ID

Answer (score 0):

Got tHe solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM
STUDENT S,COURSE C
WHERE
S.STD_ID like '%'||null||'%' and S.STD_NAME like '%'||null ||'%' and S.STD_START_DATE like '%'||null ||'%' and S.STD_END_DATE like '%'||null ||'%' and S.STD_GENDER like '%'||null||'%'
and S.COURSE_ID like '%'||null||'%' and S.COURSE_ID=C.COURSE_ID
```